# Drawing smooth lines with the mouse onto the page

Tags: java, swing

I've tried searching around, but nothing really seems to cover what I'm looking for.

I'm currently making a mini graphics editor for my course, and its working okay at the minute for the paintbrush tool, only that it doesn't seem to work very well at all if I'm moving the mouse too quickly.

The drawing is done through a mouse listener, triggering a 'draw' event while the mouse is held down. It then adds a circle (size and color based upon settings elsewhere) each time the loop rolls. The method takes the initial mouse location (MouseEvent e), and then uses a PointerInfo to update the current mouse position with some calculations around it to make sure it draws in the current place (the canvas uses a null layout).

Some code to show what It's doing:

```
void setMouseDown(MouseEvent e){
    PointerInfo mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    int mouseRelativeX = e.getX();
    int mouseRelativeY = e.getY();
    int startX = (int) mousePos.getLocation().getX();
    int startY = (int) mousePos.getLocation().getY();
    while(mouseDown){
        mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        mouseMarginX = mouseRelativeX - (startX - (int) mousePos.getLocation().getX());
        mouseMarginY = mouseRelativeY - (startY -(int) mousePos.getLocation().getY());

        if(curTool == "drawPen"){
            DrawPen drawPen = new DrawPen(toolSize, Color.BLACK);       
            add(drawPen);
            drawPen.setBounds(mouseMarginX, mouseMarginY, toolSize, toolSize);
        }else if(curTool == ""){

        }else if(curTool == ""){

        }else if(curTool == ""){

        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

If anybody has any advice on the best way to do this, then it'd be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A common problem with many 'drawing with mouse' apps. is that they try to draw a series of points rather than a series of lines between the current point and the last point. 3) `DrawPen drawPen = new DrawPen(toolSize, Color.BLACK);       
            ..
            drawPen.setBounds(mouseMarginX, mouseMarginY, toolSize, toolSize);` Though it appears in this case, that the code is adding actual components rather that doing custom drawing. ..

Comment: .. See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a start on the correct way to draw things.

Comment: `It then adds a circle` - check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of drawing Rectangles on a panel. Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method.